# Django Application: Model ImportError

Tags: python, django, import, importerror

I have a django 1.9 application using DRF with the following folder structure

```
- api/
- api/models.py
- api/serializers.py
- api/views.py
- manage.py
```

In serializers.py I have an import:

```
from api.models import Model1, Model2, ...
```

In views.py I have these imports:

```
from api.serializers import NotificationSerializer
from api.models import Model1, Model2, ...
```

Everything works fine until now. But after adding

```
from api.serializers import NotificationSerializer
```

in models.py, django starts complaining when I start the dev server:

```
File ".../api/serializers.py", line 3, in <module>
from api.models import Model1, Model2,...
ImportError: cannot import name Model1
```

I know that there must be a problem with the python import paths, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you post all of the import section of your `serializers.py` file please?

Comment: why do you want to import a serializer in you models ? that is a circular dependency

Comment: You are trying to import a function from a module which hasn't loaded yet. http://stackoverflow.com/a/746067/3142347

Comment: @maazzaa I need serialization in a post_save-method

Answer (score 0):

This would cause a circular import, since `serializers.py` imports `models.py`, and vise versa.

How to resolve this depends on what `NotificationSerializer` does. If it does not use the models, you might consider moving it to a utils file.